# importing object and using it in an Array will make the first item undefined?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a few files that I'm importing to construct an object:

```
// otis.ts
export const otisHeadline = 'Realizing the office of the future for UTC';
export const otisPreview = toCloudinaryUrl('otisPreview1.png');
export const otisClientName = 'Otis';
export const otisClientUrl = 'otis';

export const otisPreviewItem: PreviewTileProps = {
  headlineText: otisHeadline,
  client: otisClientName,
  clientUrl: otisClientUrl,
  backgroundImage: {
    desktop: otisPreview,
  },
};
```

and

```
// sm.ts
const smHeadline = 'Connecting an enterprise brand to a consumer audience';
const smClientName = 'SM';
const smClientUrl = 's-m';
const smPreview = toCloudinaryUrl('smPreview.png');

export const smPreviewItem: PreviewTileProps = {
  headlineText: smHeadline,
  client: smClientName,
  clientUrl: smClientUrl,
  backgroundImage: {
    desktop: smPreview,
  },
};
```

and then I'm import both `otisPreviewItem` and `smPreviewItem` into the main file here:

```
// ss.ts
import { otisPreviewItem } from './otis';
import { smPreviewItem } from './s-m';

export const module8: Preview = {
  tiles: [otisPreviewItem, smPreviewItem]
}
```

however when rendering, there's an error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientUrl' of undefined
```

so for my debugging process, I did `console.log(module8)` and the output is this:

```
{ tiles: 
   [ undefined,
     { headlineText: 'Connecting an enterprise brand to a consumer audience',
       client: 'SM',
       clientUrl: 's-m',
       backgroundImage: [Object] } ] }
```

The types are these:

```
export interface PreviewTileProps {
  headlineText: string;
  client: string;
  clientUrl: string;
  backgroundImage: {
    desktop: string;
    mobile?: string;
  };
  overlay?: string;
}

export interface Preview {
  tiles: PreviewTileProps[];
}
```

Theoretically this should work... but I have no idea why the first item in `tiles` is always undefined. If I hardcode this object into `module8`, it'll work, but importing it seems like it doesn't...

This happens for any object I try to import and place in here. not just `otisPreviewItem`

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: Likely a typo somewhere. That code will work

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your imported files lack of a closing single quotation mark.

Comment: sorry... that was due to my editing of the examples. there are no errors in my editor.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are accessing to `module8` inside Component.render method by accessing to `this['module8'].clientUrl`. Is it?

If not, could you please show us your current component implementation?